# vee-validate check after each character

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vee-validate

Is it possible to do this after each input character?
The check works only if you click somewhere

**password:**

```
    <div class='form-group' :class='{"form-group_invalid": errors.has("password") && errors.has("password:min")}'>
     <input
      v-validate='"required|min:8|confirmed:password_confirmation"'
      type='password'
      name='password'
      v-model='user.password'
      ref='password'
     />

     <div class='form-group__error'>{{ errors.first('password') }}</div>
   </div>
```

**password confirm:**

```
<div class='form-group' :class='{"form-group_invalid": errors.has("password:confirmed")}'>
  <input
    v-validate='"required|confirmed:password"'
    type='password'
    name='password_confirmation'
    v-model='user.passwordConfirmation'
    ref='password_confirmation'
  />

  <div class='form-group__error'>{{ errors.firstByRule('password', 'confirmed') }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding an extra attribute:

```
data-vv-validate-on="blur"
```

or by changing it globally in your main.ts where you create the VeeValidate instance

```
Vue.use(VeeValidate, {
  events: 'change|custom'
});
```

Comment: Hm...in main.ts i have ```events: 'change|blur',```, and if i change with extra attribute, its won't work for me. But if i delete ```events: 'change|blur',```, working fine.

Comment: @Alex with `events: 'change|blur'`. (an uniun type) You say that you want to validate when you change OR blur. not only on blur